# Changes not written into a CSV file after setting UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write changes to a file but I get the error :

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0159' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Other people said that you need to set the encoding to UTF-8 and so I set :

```
with open('ScrapedContent.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as write
```

After this is done the text is no longer being written to the `ScrapedContent.csv` file and the whole program becomes pretty much useless afterwards. Here is my code :

(I am providing the entire code since I don't know where the issue happens)

Desired solution :

There are "special" characters written to the file such as "č, ř, š". These are not actually special but rather normal in the 21st century but unfortunately it seems like that computers are still having a hard time understanding.

So in any case I need to write those characters to the file so they don't get broken. I don't care about what has to be done as long as the final file provides the result. I have spend about 6 hours trying to fix this now and I got nowhere.

This is the complete error output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\Reality Scrapers\SRealityContentScraper\main.py", line 113, in <module>
    writer.writerow([title.text, offers.text, address.text, phone_number, email])
  File "C:\Users\workstationone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u011b' in position 57: character maps to <undefined>
```

This is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, TimeoutException
from platform import system
from os import getcwd, getlogin
import csv

cwd = getcwd()
os = system()
user = getlogin()
browser = input("Browser name ex.: Chromium | Chrome | Firefox: ")

if os == "Linux":
    if user == "root":
        print(
            "You are executing the script as root. Make sure that the profile folder is also located in the root directory.")
        del user

if browser == "Firefox" or browser == "Firefox ESR" or browser == "Firefox Browser":
    try:
        if os == "Windows":
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=cwd + "/geckodriver.exe")
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=cwd + "/geckodriver")
    except WebDriverException:
        print("Warning 10: Firefox is not installed in the default location")
        bin_location = input("Firefox executable location: ")
        binary = FirefoxBinary(bin_location)
        if os == "Windows":
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=cwd + "/geckodriver.exe", firefox_binary=bin_location)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=cwd + "/geckodriver", firefox_binary=bin_location)
        del bin_location

elif browser == "Chrome" or browser == "Chrome Browser" or browser == "Google Chrome" or browser == "Chromium" or browser == "Chromium Browser":
    try:
        if os == "Windows":
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cwd + "/chromedriver.exe")
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cwd + "/chromedriver")
    except WebDriverException:
        print("Warning 11: Chrome/Chromium is not installed in the default location")
        bin_location = input("Chrome/Chromium executable location: ")
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = bin_location
        if os == "Windows":
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cwd + "/chromedriver.exe")
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cwd + "/chromedriver")
        del bin_location

else:
    print("Error 10: Invalid browser selected")
    input("Press ENTER to exit: ")
    exit()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('links.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as write:
    driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/adresar")
    writer = csv.writer(write)
    page_spawn = 0
    while page_spawn == 0:
        try:
            links = wait.until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.title > a")))
            # print(len(links))
            for link in links:
                print(link.get_attribute("href"))
                writer.writerow([link.get_attribute("href")])
            wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-paging-pn.icof.icon-arr-right.paging-next:not(.disabled"))).click()
        except TimeoutException:
            page_spawn = 1
            break

with open('links.csv') as read:
    reader = csv.reader(read)
    link_list = list(reader)
    with open('ScrapedContent.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as write:
        writer = csv.writer(write)
        for link in link_list:
            driver.get(', '.join(link))
            title = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.page-title span.text.ng-binding")))
            offers = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.switcher.ng-binding.ng-scope span.ng-binding.ng-scope")))
            address = wait.until(
                ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.c-aginfo__table__row td.ng-binding")))
            try:
                wait.until(
                    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.value.link.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).click()
                phone_number = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.phone.ng-binding")))
            except TimeoutException:
                pass
            try:
                wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.value.link.ng-binding"))).click()
                email = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.value.link.ng-binding")))
            except TimeoutException:
                pass
            try:
                phone_number = phone_number.text
            except AttributeError:
                phone_number = " "
                pass
            try:
                email = email.text
            except AttributeError:
                email = " "
                pass
            print(title.text, " ", offers.text, " ", address.text, " ", phone_number, " ", email)
            try:
                writer.writerow([title.text, offers.text, address.text, phone_number, email])
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: *I am providing the entire code since I don't know where the issue happens*. You would know, and so would we, if you provided *the entire stack trace*. That tells you exactly where in your code the problem is, which is why it is so important.

Comment: I have edited the post and provided the complete error output.

Comment: Does it go wrong if you for example just use `writer.writerow([title.text])` ?  If not keep adding fields until you work out which is causing the problem. Are you possibly missing a `.text` ?

Comment: Please do not deface your question which makes for unnecessary extra work for moderators on this site. Once you post a question on this site, it becomes the property of the site, and you should not deface or destroy it.

Comment: Please 1) read the site's [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) and [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) to see what you agreed to before joining the site, terms that are legal in the EU and elsewhere, and 2) desist from making personal attacks on members of this site which is in direct violation of the site's published [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is heavily based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069407/how-can-i-write-special-characters-to-a-csv-in-python).

Basically, you can't directly write unicode characters using `csv`.

You need a helper function:

```
 def utf8ify(l):
       return [str(s).encode('utf-8') for s d]
```

Then when you write the row add:

```
 writer.writerow(utf8ify([title.text, offers.text, address.text, phone_number, email]))
```

[The answer I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069407/how-can-i-write-special-characters-to-a-csv-in-python) is better than mine in every way. If you want to learn why this works, read that answer.